# What are the utilities/tools you use for developing in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am learning ASP.NET and would like to know what are the must have tools for developing in ASP.NET. These can be tools for debugging, testing, desinging or other category you think about. Please be specific to ASP.NET development. I would prefer tools that do not cost money since I am doing that for fun at home. I am already using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express.

Thanks,

Comment: Learn to use the VS you have now, it can do all you need. (except higher lvl stuff, like profiling, etc) Anything else for asp.net development costs money.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Tools**:

- Either [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) or [ASP.NET Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998306.aspx) for error logging
- [Search Engine Optimization Toolkit](http://www.iis.net/expand/SEOToolkit)
- [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

**Resources**:

- [The Offical ASP.NET site](http://www.asp.net/)
- [Scott Guthrie's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)

**Testing**:

- [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)

Not specific to ASP.NET, but useful:

- [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)
- [Scott Hanselman's Ultimate Developer and Power Users Tool List for Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx)
- [Ten Must-Have Tools Every Developer Should Download Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300497.aspx)

Comment: +1 for the Ten Must-Have Tools Every Developer Should Download Now

Comment: But, the must have tools are not specific to ASP.NET.

Comment: On the top ten tools, an excellent alternative to Snippet Compiler is LINQPad.

Comment: @Ikaso: yep, that's what I said. Some tools are useful because they target .NET, and ASP.NET relies heavily on .NET

Comment: The Web Developent Helper seems like a nice addition too. See the tool @ http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper.

Answer (score 1):

The Express Editions of Visual Studio are perfectly serviceable for learning ASP.NET.

In terms of specific utilities, I think having a good browser plugin like Firebug (Firefox) or the built-in developer console in Chrome are really handy for seeing whats going in the specific HTML or javascript.

Afterwords, if you find you need functionality thats not in the Express Edition, then upgrading to the full version of Visual Studio is highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Something to watch the response and request headers, like Firebug or Fiddler.  You can use these to see cookies, caching directives, etc...  It's a great way to learn the ins and outs of http, and since you're talking about ASP.NET, you should have a good understanding of the protocol.  I'd even take a peruse through RFC 2616, the suggested http standard, though not strictly followed by browsers.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Fiddler: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

There's also HttpWatch, but it's not cheap, but there is a basic version.

http://www.httpwatch.com/

Of course there are all those ajax/javascript libraries like jQuery, Prototype, Dojo, MooTools, etc..., though they strictly aren't utilities, but incredibly useful.